# Optional/Stream 2nd filter if 1st filter results in Optional.empty()

Tags: java, filter, java-stream, option-type

I have a method I would like to change:

```
public Optional<Package> getPackage(String holderID, String packageID){
    Holder holder = service.getHolder(holderID);
    return holder.getPackages().stream()
            .filter(model-> StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(packageID,model.getPackageId())).findAny();
}
```

Holder has a field:

```
List<Package> packages;
```

Package has fields:

```
String packageId;
String packageType;
```

I am interested in is extending the method so that it does an additional filter if the first results in an empty Optional. Is there such a way to filter by the packageId like I am above, then filter by packageType (e.g. packageType == "type1") when the first filter results in an empty optional?

I guess in general I am wondering if an *only filter if it results in a none-empty Optional or Stream* method is available?

Is there a better way of doing it than this:

```
public Optional<Package> getPackage(String holderID, String packageID){
    Holder holder = service.getHolder(holderID);
    Optional<Package> package = holder.getPackages().stream()
            .filter(model-> StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(packageID,model.getPackageId())).findAny();
    if(package.isEmpty()){
        package = holder.getPackages().stream()
                .filter(model -> StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase("type1",model.getPackageType()))
                .findAny();
    }
    return package;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `Optional.or()` (available since Java 9) to which you can pass a `Supplier` that returns another `Optional`:

```
holder.getPackages().stream()
      .filter(model-> StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(packageID,model.getPackageId())).findAny()
      .or(() -> holder.getPackages().stream()
            .filter(model -> StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase("type1",model.getPackageType()))
            .findAny())
```

Comment: Seems a useful answer to me, so don't know why it was down-voted, though it could use some explanation, including a note that [`or(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#or(java.util.function.Supplier)) was added in Java 9.

Comment: Cool thanks, just 2 questions... I assume if the filter.findAny in the or doesn't find any then it returns Optional.empty to the or which in turn sets it to holder? 2nd question, what about efficiency - I am concerned that the 2nd lambda in the or is nested, or does this not matter when doing functional programming? Just concerned that you could keep on doing .or() and going a logical level deeper with the new lambda.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in more general way for more than two cases (but in this case it will be more complicated). With stream of `Predicate` you can give as many conditions as you need.:

```java
Stream<Predicate<Package>> predicates = Stream.of(
        model-> StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(packageID,model.getPackageId()),
        model -> StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase("type1",model.getPackageType())
);
Optional<Package> packageOptional = predicates
        .map(p -> holder.getPackages().stream().filter(p::test).findAny())
        .filter(Optional::isPresent).map(Optional::get)
        .findAny();
```

It will be searching for first `findAny` for given predictor. Otherwise it will return empty Optional